# Некорректная запись в БД при использовании Factory в Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, factory

Проблема при записи в MySQL БД в поле status,"enum('0','1','2')".
Запизывает число на 1 меньше. Если передаю 1 запишет 0; 2 ->1; Не пойму в чем проблема.

Я использую Factory в Laravel

```
    $factory->define(Tasks::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
        'title' => $faker->name,
        'status' => TasksStatus::getRandomValue(),
        'description' => $faker->sentence(15),
        'project_id' => function() {
            return factory(Projects::class)->create()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

В TasksStatus следюющий код

```
final class TasksStatus extends Enum
{
const New = 0;
const In_progress = 1;
const Done = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему изменив

```
const New = new;
const In_progress = progress;
const Done = done;
```

также и в БД.
Проблема в том что в поле status ожидается строка, а я передавал число.